# Build XML file with XSLT to filter on severals childs nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, ssis

I've a big xml file from ICECAT. And I want take only some informations. It's in the following of this subject [filter-dynamically-xml-child-element-with-xslt-with-ssis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45082455/filter-dynamically-xml-child-element-with-xslt-with-ssis)

Now I've a categoriesList XML file like this:

```
<ICECAT-interface>
<Response Date="Tue Jul 25 16:00:10 2017" ID="29306604" Request_ID="1500991209" Status="1">
<CategoriesList>
  <Category ID="2597" LowPic="http://images.icecat.biz/img/low_pic/2597-5095.jpg" Score="471102" Searchable="0" ThumbPic="http://images.icecat.biz/thumbs/CAT2597.jpg" UNCATID="43223323" Visible="0">
    <Name ID="1088701" Value="fiber optic adapters" langid="1"/>
    <Name ID="1595015" Value="glasvezeladapters" langid="2"/>
    <Name ID="1088703" Value="adaptateurs de fibres optiques" langid="3"/>
    <Name ID="1245208" Value="LWL-Steckverbinder" langid="4"/>
    <Name ID="1088705" Value="adattatori di fibra ottica" langid="5"/>
    <Name ID="1125574" Value="adaptadores de fibra óptica" langid="6"/>
    <Name ID="1147616" Value="lyslederadapter" langid="7"/>

   <ParentCategory ID="242">
    <Names>
      <Name ID="485" langid="1">networking</Name>
      <Name ID="471244" langid="2">netwerken</Name>
      <Name ID="343986" langid="3">réseaux</Name>
      <Name ID="436999" langid="4">Netzwerke</Name>
      <Name ID="1051724" langid="5">reti</Name>
      <Name ID="1041258" langid="6">redes</Name>
      <Name ID="34261" langid="7">netværk</Name>
      <Name ID="530435" langid="8">сети/коммуникации</Name>

    </Names>
   </ParentCategory>
  </Category>
  <Category ID="4601" LowPic="http://images.icecat.biz/img/low_pic/4601-990.jpg" Score="12621" Searchable="0" ThumbPic="http://images.icecat.biz/thumbs/CAT4601.jpg" UNCATID="56101688" Visible="0">
```

I need some attributes in `Category` node like `ID`, `LowPic`... some `Name` nodes and `ID` from the `ParentCategory` node.

I tried this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:output  method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/ICECAT-interface">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Response"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Response">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="CategoriesList"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CategoriesList">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Category"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Category">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Name"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Name[@langid=1 or @langid=3]">
        <Category>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../@ID|../@LowPic|../@ThumbPic|../@UNCATID||@langid|@Value" />
        </Category>
    </xsl:template>        
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I don't know if it's the better methods and I don't have the  `ID` of the `ParentCategory` node.

**UPDATE**
Sorry I forgot the result What I Want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Categories>
<Category ID="2597" LowPic="http://images.icecat.biz/img/low_pic/2597-5095.jpg" ThumbPic="http://images.icecat.biz/thumbs/CAT2597.jpg" UNCATID="43223323" name="fiber optic adapters" langid="1" ParentCategory="242"/>
  <Category ID="2597" LowPic="http://images.icecat.biz/img/low_pic/2597-5095.jpg" ThumbPic="http://images.icecat.biz/thumbs/CAT2597.jpg" UNCATID="43223323" name="adaptateurs de fibres optiques" langid="3" ParentCategory="242"/>
 ....
```

**UPDATE 2**
I modify the XSLT file I inverse my filter position. Now I've the goods records, just lake of parentcategory id

Comment: How would your desired output look like?

Comment: Can you make sure your output corresponds exactly with your input, please? Your current expected output references the text "Others phones" which is not in your input. It would also help if you made your input XML well formed. At the moment it is missing some closing tags. Thank you!

Comment: I do it. I Change example in 1st post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to output a `Category` for each `Name` with a `langid` attribute of 1 or 3. In which case you need to move the condition to the `xsl:apply-templates`

```
<xsl:template match="Category">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Name[@langid=1 or @langid=3]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, within the template matching `Name` you can create an attribute for the ParentCategoryId like so

```
 <xsl:attribute name="ParentCategoryId">
    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::ParentCategory[1]/@ID" />
 </xsl:attribute>
```

And similarly for the `Name` attribute.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:output  method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/ICECAT-interface">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Response"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Response">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="CategoriesList"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CategoriesList">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Category"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Category">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Name[@langid=1 or @langid=3]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Name">
        <Category>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../@ID|../@LowPic|../@ThumbPic|../@UNCATID|@langid" />
            <xsl:attribute name="Name">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Value" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="ParentCategoryId">
              <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::ParentCategory[1]/@ID" />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </Category>
    </xsl:template>        
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, you can simplify the `Name` template by using Attribute Value Templates

```
<xsl:template match="Name">
    <Category Name="{@Value}" ParentCategoryId="{following-sibling::ParentCategory[1]/@ID}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="../@ID|../@LowPic|../@ThumbPic|../@UNCATID|@langid" />
    </Category>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Super, but I don't know if parentcategory will be always after, then following-sibling is perhaps not enough. Then I replace by '<Category Name="{@Value}" ParentCategoryId="{../ParentCategory/@ID}">'

Comment: And I Add filtrer on empty value : '<xsl:template match="Name[string-length(@Value)!=0 and (@langid=1 or @langid=3)]">'